# SQL Query Taking 30 Seconds From Web Site, Instant on Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that i'm executing from my ASP.NET web site.

It takes 30 seconds to return. When i run the SQL profile trace, i see it indeed takes 30 seconds (so the lag is somewhere between the web server and the database).

When i grab what's in the trace, and execute it locally on SQL Server, it is -instant-.

Here is the two queries. The first one from the web server (executed using Entity Framework), and the second one from SQL Server Management Studio.

```
EventClass          TextData                                                                                                                        ApplicationName                                 CPU     Reads   Writes  Duration    ClientProcessID SPID    StartTime               EndTime
RPC:Completed       exec sp_executesql N'FindQuestions @Query, @LocationId',N'@Query nvarchar(7),@LocationId int',@Query=N'what is',@LocationId=1   EntityFrameworkMUE                              28330   146818  0       30063       2764            87      2014-02-12 19:42:00.933 2014-02-12 19:42:30.997
SQL:BatchCompleted  exec sp_executesql N'FindQuestions @Query, @LocationId',N'@Query nvarchar(7),@LocationId int',@Query=N'what is',@LocationId=1   Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query  344     16604   0       385         22236           62      2014-02-12 19:42:57.803 2014-02-12 19:42:58.190
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be [parameter sniffing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using entity framework is not so good at generating optimal queries.

Please have a look at [this thread on SQL Server forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6e5353b9-4837-4022-a535-5408ed6f852a/stored-procedure-running-slow-in-adonet?forum=sqldataaccess). Clearing the SQL Server plan cache should help.

Comment: well entity framework isnt generating anything, it's just calling a stored procedure. but yes, clearing the plan cache worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing Stored Procedure in SQL Query Analyzer >> How much time it takes? If it takes say >20 seconds then there is problem in Stored Procedure which you have prepared. Secondly if less than <10 seconds then need to check the connectivity between web server and database server.

Also would like to have proper information on is

1. Both Web and Database on Local system
2. Both Web and Database on different but Local system
3. Both Web and Database on different but Servers and trying to open web page through Internet

So can exactly trace where the problem is